# How can I match Optional<*>.none in a Swift switch statement?

Tags: swift, swift3, pattern-matching

What can I match on here to make this test pass?

```
func testMatchNone() {
    let none: String? = nil
    let foo: Any = none

    switch foo {
    case nil:
        break

    default:
        XCTFail()
    }
}
```

Trying `Optional.none` the compiler complains it doesn't know what the generic type of the optional is, which is fair. But I don't care, I just want to match if it's a `nil`/`.none` of whatever generic type.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out:

```
func testMatchNone() {
    let none: String? = nil
    let foo: Any = none

    switch foo {
    case Optional<Any>.none:
        break

    default:
        XCTFail()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `case nil:`?

Comment: hah it compiles, but doesn't behave as expected. `Optional<Any>.none` works, though